# How to make the code run reversly? from Roman number to decimal number

Tags: java, methods, while-loop

I already wrote a code that convert from decimal number to roman number, however, i want it to do opposite way so how can i make it possible? (This is my previous code: http://pastebin.com/QFKi0xJh ) thank you! and here is my code right now. 
I am just a beginner so my code is look little bit basic, please apology for that.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Fill in the body
    Scanner in= new Scanner(System.in);
    String user = promptUserForNumeral(in);
    while (user.length()!=0) {
        int numb= convertNumeralToNumber(user);
        System.out.println("The numeral "+user+ " is the decimal number "+numb);
        user = promptUserForNumeral(in);
    }
}


private static String promptUserForNumeral(Scanner inScanner) {
    // Fill in the body
    System.out.println("Enter a roman numeral (Q to quit): ");
    String i = inScanner.nextLine();
    while (i.length()>=0) {
        if (i.length()==0) {
            System.out.println("ERROR! You must enter a non-empty line!");
            System.out.println("Enter a roman numeral (Q to quit): ");
            i = inScanner.nextLine();
        }
        else if ( i.length()==1 && i.charAt(0)=='q' || i.charAt(0)=='Q') {
            System.out.println("Goodbye!");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
    return i;
}


private static int convertNumeralToNumber(String numeral) {
    // Fill in the body
    int n=0;
    if (numeral.equalsIgnoreCase("m")) {            
        n-=1000;
    }
    else if (numeral.equalsIgnoreCase("d")) {
        n=500;  
    }
    else if (numeral.equalsIgnoreCase("c")) {
        n=100;
    }
    else if (numeral.equalsIgnoreCase("l")) {
        n=50;
    }
    else if (numeral.equalsIgnoreCase("x")) {
        n=10;
    }
    else if (numeral.equalsIgnoreCase("v")) {
        n=5;
    }
    else if (numeral.equalsIgnoreCase("i")) {
        n=1;
    }
    return n;

}
```

Comment: The minus in `n-=1000;` looks odd

Comment: I would recommend working iteratively.  I think you've already got it working for one-character strings.  Next make it work for strings where the characters are all the same (like MMM or II).  Then make it work for strings where all the parts are added (like DCXVI).  Then make it work for strings where some parts are subtracted (like XCIV).  Lastly, add some validation, to ensure that the string is actually a valid Roman Numeral.  Test that it works correctly after each step.

Comment: Your `promptUserForNumeral()` will never return a string. And your `convertNumeralToNumber()` does not take the positions of the letters into account (in addition to the minus problem). You'll have to re-think both of them.

Comment: @RC. sorry for not make it clean. the minus is not suppose to be there.

Comment: @DavidWallace thank i will try to work on it, i hope i can find the solution.